# Pytorch gradient computation

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient

I am trying to figure out how exactly the function `grad` works.
This is my code :

```
A = torch.Tensor(2, 3).uniform_(-1, 1).requires_grad_()
B = torch.Tensor(3, 1).uniform_(-1, 1).requires_grad_()
o = torch.matmul(A,B) 
print("A : ", A)
print("B : ", B)
do_dinput = torch.autograd.grad(o, A, grad_outputs=torch.ones(2, 1))
print('Size do/dA :', (do_dinput[0].size()))
```

I was expecting `torch.Size([1, 3])` to be printed, because the derivative of `AB` w.r.t `A` is `B^T`. However, I got `torch.Size([2, 3])`.

Is there something wrong with my code, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you get is the grad starting from o back-propagated through the computational graph to A. In the end you have the grad for every value in A.

It is the same as doing the following

```
A = torch.Tensor(2, 3).uniform_(-1, 1).requires_grad_()
B = torch.Tensor(3, 1).uniform_(-1, 1).requires_grad_()
o = torch.matmul(A,B).sum()
o.backward()
print("A : ", A)
print("B : ", B)
print(A.grad)
```

`A.grad` in this example and `do_dinput`are the same. If you look at the grad tensor it is just `B^T` in both rows.

To make it a bit more visual what happens. We have A and B as input and some function f(...) which takes all values from A and B as input and calculates some value. In this case the function is sum(AB).
Note: The summation doesn't change the gradients in any way.

```
A = x_1 x_2 x_3
    x_4 x_5 x_6
B = y_1
    y_2
    y_3
o = x_1 * y_1 + x_2 * y_2 + x_3 * y_3
    x_4 * y_1 + x_5 * y_2 + x_6 * y_3
f(x_1,...,x_6, y_1, y_2, y_3) = x_1 * y_1 + x_2 * y_2 + x_3 * y_3 + x_4 * y_1 + x_5 * y_2 + x_6 * y_3
```

If you now calculate the gradient you derive f(...) in respect to all variables. So for x_1 it would be

```
df/dx_1 = y_1
```

So the grad value in A for x_1 is equal to y_1. This is done for all other values. So in the end you get a grad value for all entries in A and B.

It works the same in your example you just skip the summing of the tensor.